# How to convert csv to json in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I able to convert csv into pojo with the help of camel bindy. But I need to convert the string to json easily?

I able to do my splitting the string.But is there any efficient methods to do it?

My pojo Class:-

```java
@CsvRecord(separator = ",",skipFirstLine = true)

public class Sample
{

 //some fields

}
```

Processor Class:-

```java
String samples=exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

String[] strings=samples.split("}");
System.out.println(strings[0]);
for(String strings1:strings)
{
    String[] strings2=strings1.split("'");
    for(int i=0;i<strings2.length;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==1) {
            System.out.println(strings2[i]);
        }
    }
}
//Is there is efficient method we can do to convert the String to list of json. Assuming csv contains multiple record
```

Route Builder :-

```java
public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private final BindyCsvDataFormat bindy=new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.company.model.Sample.class);;
    @Override
    public void configure()  {

      from("file:/path/?fileName=CCO_SUMMARY_20190315_165800 copy.csv&noop=true").unmarshal(bindy).process(new MyProcessor()).
               to("file:/path/?fileName=akshay.txt");

    }
}
```

Eager to know if there is any efficient method to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.json()**

see [camel json data format](http://camel.apache.org/json.html)   ie: `.json().log("${body}")`

In your scenario for example:

```
from("file:/path/?fileName=CCO_SUMMARY_20190315_165800 copy.csv&noop=true")
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .marshal()
    .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).log("${body}")
    .to("file:/path/?fileName=akshay.txt");
```

where `json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)` forces the use of the jackson library for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.It was helpful.I stuck in main method.I have Thread.sleep(5000) in main method.CamelContext camelContext=new DefaultCamelContext();
       SimpleRouteBuilder simpleBuilder=new SimpleRouteBuilder();
       try {
           camelContext.addRoutes(simpleBuilder);
           camelContext.start();
         //Thread.sleep(1000); how to get rid of this Thread.sleep and stop the route when it is done.

Comment: I never used it standalone however you can find documentation http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html and examples online https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/main/MainExample.java most of the examples in the apache site are broken but you can find the graal at: https://github.com/apache/camel if you are using spring boot https://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use camel bindy t unmarshal csv to List of POJO
2. Do mapping if required base on output format
3. marshal mapped data using Jacson o Gson in Came route.

```
    from("file:/input/path/?noop=true")
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .marshal()
    .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).log("${body}")
    .to("file:/path/?fileName=test.txt");
```